# How to initialize shared variables before parallel test in scalatest

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scalatest, parallel-testing

I have scalatest codes like following:

```
class myTest extends FlatSpec with ParallelTestExecution {  

    val testSuiteId: String = GenerateSomeRandomId() 

    it should "print test id" in { 
        println(testSuiteId)
    } 

    it should "print test id again" in { 
        println(testSuiteId) 
    }
}
```

The two tests cannot print the testSuiteId I generate before them. Instead they regenerate the ID and print it. I understand that because of ParallelTestExecution which extends OneInstancePerTest, each test here runs on its own instance and have a copy of the variable "testSuiteId".

But I do want a fixed Id for this test suite and each test case in this suite have access to this fixed it without modifying it. I tried to create the fixed id in BeforeAll{ } but still it didn't work.

How should I achieve what I want?

Comment: Why do you need `ParallelTestExecution`?

Comment: @pedromss Hi I just want to run all test specs in parallel. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to work around it would be to put the shared state in some sort of external object:

```
object SuiteId {
  lazy val id: String = GenerateSomeRandomId()
}
```

Admittedly this is very much a hack, and I wouldn't be surprised if scalatest has a way to handle this built-in which I am unaware of.

Comment: Thank you! That's the best solution I have so far. Will still do investigation on the scalatest-way to do this.